# Firebase server shows only the latest value

Tags: firebase, esp32

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

My realtime database rules look like this. It only shows the latest data, but I want to store the previous data too. What should I do? I'm unable to solve the problem. The resources found on the internet did not use anything special.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Firebase Realtime Database to keep historical data, nor does it have anything to do with the security rules of your database.

To keep historical data in Firebase you will have to ensure that new data doesn't overwrite existing data. If you use one of the client-side SDKs to write to Firebase, you can do by using `push()` or `childByAutoId()` to generate a new unique key for each data point. If you're using the REST API, the equivalent would be to use a `POST` request rather than `PUT`.